# Can a 180 watt mobile charger charge at 140 watts?

Tags: power-supply, laptop, mobile

I am not sure if its the right place to ask but the question is related to electronics so I assume I can ask here .

The charger(power supply) output rating is 180 watts (9Ax20V) and 15 watts(5Vx3A) , which is mentioned on the power adapter.

Can it charge at a wattage inbetween like 140 watts? For example if a device supports 140 watts maximum will it chargee at 15 watts or 140 watts because apprently 180 watts is not supported.

Comment: I dont think its duplicate question ?

Comment: it's not a battery charger, it is a power supply ... the battety charger is built into the device that contains the battery

Comment: There seems to be an usual misconception/confusion between ability to supply and consume. The PS can provide 180W, but the device will consume anything from 0-to-140W, there is no contradiction.

Comment: How does that exactly work ? Where does the extra current go ?

Comment: What is the significance of the ``and 15 watts`` part of the question? Does the power adapter produce more than one voltage supply?

Comment: Yes 15 watts (5Vx3A) has different voltage and current

Comment: And that reflects my assumption . I thought the power supply will only provide 180 watts only when a 180 watts capable device is connected . And will simply switch to 15 watts if the upper limit of device is less than 180 watts .

Comment: Thought experiment: when I switch on a 10 W light bulb connected to the Irish 5000 MW national grid what will happen to the extra 4,999,999,990 W? Answer: nothing. The lamp will draw 10 W.

Comment: If both your power supply and the connected device (load) support PD (Power Delivery) or a similar protocol, they should negotiate a suitable voltage and current. Since we don't know anything about your power supply or the load, your question isn't answerable.

Comment: @BhavishyaYadav this topic is not about circuit design

Comment: @Transistor well you cant directly use it you will need a transformer or the bulb will fuse . And The power adapter has a small transformer which can supply 20 volts from 240 volts mains supply . My question was can a power adapter provide voltage and current other than the mentioned output on the adapter .

Comment: Regarding the bulb, it won't fuse because there's a transformer down the road from my house. Another though experiment: I have a 95 W power supply on my laptop. What will happen when I put the laptop to sleep with the power supply still connected?

Comment: @BhavishyaYadav This question is off topic https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @StarCat My question is can a power adapter provide voltage and current other than the mentioned output on the adapter . If this is answerable . It is a regular mobile charger .

Comment: @Transistor Charge the device and then power supply turns off ? Maybe you are referring to charge overnight function in mobiles ?

Comment: No, the power supply doesn't turn off. It stays on. The power supply is generally a **constant voltage** output. The current will depend entirely on what the load draws. If the load is switched off no current is drawn while the voltage remains constant. V x 0 = 0 W. The power supply is **not constant power output*** it **is constant voltage output, variable current** (the same as the supply to my house).